# Docker - Problem with environment variables

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a DockerFile, with aim to run some R scripts with environment variables, passed to the `docker run` command. I'm failing to pass environment variables in to my image at the moment. Is my understanding of them wrong?

Trimmed down DockerFile:

```
# get R
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.5.0
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; apt-get -y update \
  && apt-get install -y git-core \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev \
  libssl-dev
WORKDIR /payload/

# a testing environment variable
ENV myvar hello-world
RUN echo $myvar
```

Running `docker build -t jp/hello-world .` seems to work and prints out `hello-world`. (from location of DockerFile)

When I run `docker run --env myvar = test jp/hello-world`,

I get `docker: invalid reference format.`

I'm running on Windows, with cmd, and docker Version 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513)

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong, would be great!

Comment: no space `docker run --env myvar=test jp/hello-world`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spaces around the equals:

```
docker run --env myvar=test jp/hello-world
```

Also, this question doesn't actually involve R.

Comment: Thank you, yeah you are right about R. The reason I included it was in case it was causing any issues as I had no idea what the problem was!